# Russian words in 'From' Sendmail

Tags: mail, sendmail

How to set Russian letters 'from' header in mail?
Example:
[image: from set]

I use Webasyst Mailer app and PHP to send emails.

How to set this in sendmail?

Comment: Which app/tool/propgramming language do you use to send emails?

Comment: tool: webasyst mailer, pl: php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand:

1. webasyst uses swiftmailer
2. swift mailer takes care of non US-ASCII (non plain english) characters in email headers
   [non-ASCII characters is email adrress itself (info@molodost.bz) is a longer story]

---

https://swiftmailer.symfony.com/docs/headers.html#text-headers

> If the header contains any characters that are outside of the US-ASCII range however, they will be encoded. This is nothing to be concerned about since mail clients will decode them back:

```
  $subject = $message->getHeaders()->get('Subject');
  $subject->setValue('contains – dash');
  echo $subject->toString();

  /*
  Subject: contains =?utf-8?Q?=E2=80=93?= dash
  */
```

Answer (score 0):

Per [RFC 822](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc822/3_Lexical.html#z1), header field names and their contents must be ASCII-encoded. If the software you are using does not correctly perform this encoding for you, then it is a bug in the software and should be reported to its developers. Sendmail (or other MTAs) will only accept valid messages. Other RFCs specify how to encode non-ASCII text in mail headers, such as [1342](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/rfc1342/).